# Getting the keyevent info from Virtual Keyboard of symbian touch devices

Tags: qt, symbian, virtual-keyboard

Is there any way to obtain the keypress info for the green-tick (green check marked key) present in the input panel/ virtual keyboard?

Our application is for symbian touch devices. In my application I wanted the url to start loading as soon as the QLineEdit has been edited i.e., as soon as the green check marked key in VKB has been pressed.

I tried using the CloseSoftwareInputPanel event to get notified when the editing is completed in the QLineEdit i.e., when the green check marked key is pressed in the VKB, but that event occurs only after the QLineEdit loses focus (when I tap anywhere on the screen). Is there any other way to get it done?

Thanks

Comment: See http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Detecting_virtual_keyboard_open_and_close_events_in_Symbian%5E3

Answer (score 0):

The virtual keyboard is implemented as a front-end processor (FEP) and it's quite invisible to applications.

Note that there are Symbian touch devices that also have a physical keyboard. Not for those devices alone, you should have a Go button or similar and observe `returnPressed` signal.

Comment: I have a Go button, the url loads just fine when I click on that. But my requirement is to load it immediately after tapping on that green check marked button in VKB, without having to tap on the screen for anything! (mean to say, once the url has been changed it should start loading)